# Mostrar textfield ou textarea java

Tags: java, swing

Não consigo mostrar palavras no textfield (ou textarea) no meu código, várias horas nisto e ainda não consegui.

Tenho aqui um [link para o código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68405/jogo-da-memoria-com-chat-gr%C3%A1fico).
As linhas mais importantes são estas, mas se quiserem testar o código todo, fica mais fácil de ajudar, acho eu.

```
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

private JTextArea textArea;
int player;
private DataInputStream input;
private JTextField id;


JPanel middlePanel=new JPanel();     
JTextArea display=new JTextArea(12,12);
display.setEditable(true); //false
JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(display);
scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
middlePanel.add(scroll);
window.add(middlePanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
display.setText("Jogador(Player) 1");


middlePanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(),"Informações                            Chat"));        
JTextArea display2=new JTextArea(12,12);
display2.setEditable(true); 
JScrollPane scroll2=new JScrollPane(display2);
scroll2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
middlePanel.add(scroll2);
window.add(middlePanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
window.pack();
window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
window.setVisible(true);    
window.resize(700,500);
```

**tenho dúvida principalmente nesta parte de código:**

```
public void run()
{
    // Primeiro a jogar jogador 1, segundo 2
    try 
    {          
        player=input.readChar();
        textArea.setText("You are player \""+ player + "\"");
        myTurn=(player == '1' ? true : false);
    }
```

Resumidamente:
O texto entre aspas " " não é mostrado para o textArea ou textField (aparece só os quadrados em branco com barras verticais de deslocamento).
Por isso estou mesmo a rasca, tenho de entregar o trabalho em poucos dias.

O único texto que é mostrado é display.setText("Jogador(Player) 1");

De resto o JtextArea está tudo em branco.
Não consigo identificar o problema.

Comment: Esta pergunta tem pouco mais de dois anos, o código está incompleto e o link é para uma outra pergunta já deletada do mesmo autor que tinha apenas algumas poucas coisas a mais que não ajudariam a responder a pergunta. As partes faltantes do código não tem como serem preenchidas por quem quiser respondê-la. Depois de tanto tempo, é improvável que o AP ainda tenha interesse nela. Assim sendo, infelizmente essa pergunta não tem como ser respondida de forma adequada e é improvável que o autor volte para corrigi-la. Logo, infelizmente não há outro fim possível a ela que não seja o fechamento.

Answer (score 0):

Tente Colocar no seu código mais uma aspa depois do ultimo sinal de + , aparentemente parece faltar uma , quem sabe resolve.

```
textArea.setText("You are player \""+ player + ""\"");
```

Comment: Dá erro illegal character:: '\'. Mesmo com System.out.println("123"). Na linha acima de // Primeiro a jogar jogador 1, segundo 2. Não mostra "123", nem na saida da consola do netbeans nem no textArea da janela do cliente.